# Dynamically change StartDate on a query depending on ClientId

Tags: t-sql

I want to return the sum of daily spent since the beginning of the current insertion order (invoice) for a number of clients. Each client unfortunately has a different start date for the current insertion order.

I don't have any problem to pull the start date for each client but I don't get how to create a sort of lookup to a table with the start dates associated to each client.

Let's say I have a table `IO`:

```
ClientId StartDate  
1        2014-10-01  
2        2014-10-04  
3        2014-09-17
...
```

And another table with the `DailySpend` for each Client:

```
Date          Client    Spend
2014-10-01    1         2325
2014-10-01    2         195
2014-10-01    3         434
2014-10-02    1         43624
...
```

Now, I would simply want to check for each client how much we spend from the start date of the current insertion order until yesterday.

Comment: Why not try, `select sum(spend) from Dailyspend dp group by client where date >= (select startdate from IO where clientid = dp.client)`. This should mostly work. You might want to make the necessary changes to query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
  from IO 
  join DailySpend 
    on IO.ClientId = DailySpend.Client 
   and DailySpend.Date <= IO.StartDate 
   and datediff(dd, getdate(), DailySpend.Date) <= 1

select DailySpend.Client, sum(DailySpend.Spend)
  from IO 
  join DailySpend 
    on IO.ClientId = DailySpend.Client 
   and DailySpend.Date >= IO.StartDate 
   and datediff(dd, getdate(), DailySpend.Date) <= 1
 group by DailySpend.Client
```

you may need to flip the date order in the datediff

Answer (score 0):

May be something lyk this

```
SELECT a.client,
       Sum(b.spend)
FROM   [IO] a
       JOIN DailySpend b
         ON a.id = b.id
         and a.startdate=>b.date
WHERE  b.date <= Dateadd(dd, -1, Cast(Getdate() AS DATE))
GROUP  BY client
```